# How to know when recyclerview smoothscroll ends

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling, linearlayoutmanager

Overview:

The recycler view has a horizontal layout manager, in that linear layout manager i override the canScrollHorizontally method, so that the user can not scroll by himself.

Also i have a RecyclerView.SmoothScroller to change visible item programmatically, (the recycler view has a PagerSnapHelper attached, each item of the recylcler cover the entire screen, with this feature the recycler view works like ViewPager).

But when i call the method myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScrollerForward) the scroll can not been performed because the linear layout manager canScrollHorizontally return always false.

If i make canScrollHorizontally method returns true before call startSmoothScroll it works, but how to know when myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScrollerForward) ends? so that i can move the variable returned by canScrollHorizontally to false again.

Here is the code:

```
private RecyclerView rvCards;
private LinearLayoutManager manager;
private RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScrollerForward;
private int currentPosition;
private boolean horizontalScroll = false;

rvCards = findViewById(R.id.rvCards);
manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, 
false)
{
        @Override
        public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
            return horizontalScroll;
        }
 };

rvCards.setLayoutManager(manager);

PagerSnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rvCards);

smoothScrollerForward = new LinearSmoothScroller(this){
        @Override
        protected int getHorizontalSnapPreference() {
            return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_END;
        }
    };

    ivForwardCard.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    smoothScrollerForward.setTargetPosition(++currentPosition); 
    rvCards.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScrollerForward);
    });


     public void changeItem(int position) {          
            horizontalScroll = true;
            ivForwardCard.performClick();
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this